# Cloud9 + sails.js + phpmyadmin

Tags: node.js, phpmyadmin, sails.js, cloud9-ide

I have problem with creating basic sails.js application on Cloud9 environment and connecting it to MySQL.

Steps I'm making:

- Creating Cloud9 project
- installing sails: `npm -g install sails`
- creating project: `sails new test`
- lifting: `cd testProject/` and `sails lift`

  - Here it's working
- Adding mySQL support: `mysql-ctl start`

  - still working
- adding phpMyAdmin support: `phpmyadmin-ctl install`

And here, my application stops working. I'm getting exception:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
  at listen (net.js:1065:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
  at Array.async.auto.start [as 0] (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/start.js:29:35)
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:484:38
  at _each (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
  at Object.async.auto (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:455:9)
  at Sails.startServer (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/start.js:16:11)
  at Sails.emit (events.js:92:17)
  at Sails.emitter.emit (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:50:11)
  at afterBootstrap (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:56:11)
  at bootstrapDone (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:51:14)
  at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (/home/ubuntu/workspace/testProject/config/bootstrap.js:16:3)
  at Sails.runBootstrap (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:44:25)
  at Sails.bound [as runBootstrap] (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
  at Sails.initialize (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:48:9)
  at bound (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:607:21
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
  at iterate (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:612:34
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:201:13
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:451:17
  at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:441:17
  at _each (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
  at Object.taskComplete (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.35/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:440:13)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
```

Additionally I'm getting info about problem with starting my app, and ability to kill the process. Of course killing does not help.

Could  youplease help  me with that?

Answer (score 1):

So what's happening is that you're starting your sails server, which binds to port 8080, and then you try to install phpmyadmin which tries to start apache (at port 8080 too!) causing it to actually fail since the port is already in use. You will have to stop sails before trying to install / run phpmyadmin since two servers can't listen on the same port.

Comment: can I change somehow port of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: you can, but you won't be able to access it anymore. As I mentioned, only one port is forwarded on your hosted workspace. You can run both, just make sure you don't run them together. Shutdown apache before you lift sails, and close sails before you run apache.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention it, but I should've. Cloud9 hosted workspaces currently only forward one port, i.e. port 8080